# android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" not centering in landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/WebView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `WebView` is centered in portrait, but when I switch to landscape it seems aligned to the left of the `RelativeLayout`. Can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Are you sure that the web view is left aligned, or are the web page contents of the web view left aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like the HTML was the problem and I used align="center" in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Create a qualifier for landscape mode and give it one more try.

Comment: qualifier? not sure what you mean... can you give an example?